# Debit, Credit not showing correct result on Same Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

Scenario : I am working on Users Accounts where Users add amount to there account (Credit) and they withdraw their desire amount from their account (Debit), all is going correct but when User credit or debit on same dates it gives me wrong result (Balance). here refno is reference of user. here is my Query

```
  declare @startdate date='2013-01-02',
            @enddate date='2013-01-12';


    With summary(id,refno,transdate,cr,dr,balance)
    as
    (
    select id,
           RefNo,
        Cast(TransDate as Varchar),
         cr,
         dr,
           (cr-dr)+( Select ISNULL(Sum(l.Cr-l.Dr) ,0)
         From Ledger l
         Where l.TransDate<Ledger.TransDate and refno=001 )  as balance 
    from Ledger 
    ),
    openingbalance(id,refno,transdate,cr,dr,balance)
    As (
    select top 1 '' id,'OPENING BAL','','','',balance
    from summary
    where transdate<@startdate
    order by transdate desc
    )


    select *
    from openingbalance
    union

    Select *
    From summary
    where transdate between @startdate and @enddate and refno=001 order by transdate
```

[image: Here is Result of my Query]

Comment: this is because of same date.add one more condition after and refno=001
in inner sub query and exclude dr belonging to id 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because when you query for the previous balance you are only looking at records that have a `transdate` earlier than the current record, so this means any records that have the same date will not be included.

The solution here would be to use a more unique sequential value, in your example you could use the ID value as the sequential identifier instead. However, ID values are not always the best for ensuring sequence. I would recommend extending your `transdate` column to use a more precise value and include the time of the transactions. Seconds would likely be enough precision if you can guarantee that there will never be multiple transactions made within a given second, but whatever you decide you need to be confident there will not be any duplicates.

---

In an attempt to provide a code change solution that will work with your existing data you can try the following, which uses the `id` value to determine if a record is prior to the current record:

Change the following line:

```
Where l.TransDate<Ledger.TransDate and refno=001 )  as balance
```

to this:

```
Where l.ID<Ledger.ID and refno=001 )  as balance
```

Comment: i made changes in my query account to your hint to transferdate to date and time but it also gives me wrong result, Would u please suggest me some suggestions

Comment: @SaeedKhan: I would need to see your new table structure, with example data (like your current screenshot). Why doesn't it work? the same problem as before?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL 2012 or above, then instead of

```
SELECT id, RefNo, TransDate,cr, dr, (cr-dr) + (Select ISNULL(Sum(l.Cr-l.Dr) ,0) 
FROM Ledger l 
WHERE Cast(l.TransDate as datetime) < Cast(Ledger.TransDate as datetime) 
AND refno=001) as balance from Ledger
```

Use:

```
SELECT id, RefNo, TransDate, cr, dr, SUM(cr- dr) OVER(ORDER BY TransDate ROWS 
BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS balance
```

Answer (score 0):

After hint by @musefan i made changes to query and it is working as i want. here is query for Date Base

```
declare @startdate date='2013-01-02',
        @enddate date='2013-01-12';


With summary(id,refno,transdate,cr,dr,balance)
as
(
select id,
       RefNo,
   TransDate,
     cr,
     dr,
       (cr-dr)+( Select ISNULL(Sum(l.Cr-l.Dr) ,0)
     From Ledger l
     Where Cast(l.TransDate as datetime)< Cast(Ledger.TransDate as datetime) and refno=001 )  as balance 
from Ledger 
),
openingbalance(id,refno,transdate,cr,dr,balance)
As (
select top 1 '' id,'OPENING BAL','','','',balance
from summary
where transdate<@startdate
order by transdate desc
)


select id,refno,Cast(TransDate as varchar) as datetime,cr,dr,balance
from openingbalance
union

Select id,refno,Cast(TransDate as varchar)as datetime,cr,dr,balance
From summary
where transdate between @startdate and @enddate and refno=001 order by Cast(TransDate as varchar)
```

and Another Query Id Based

```
declare @startdate date='2013-01-02',
        @enddate date='2013-01-12';


With summary(id,refno,transdate,cr,dr,balance)
as
(
select id,
       RefNo,
   TransDate,
     cr,
     dr,
       (cr-dr)+( Select ISNULL(Sum(l.Cr-l.Dr) ,0)
     From Ledger l
     Where l.id < Ledger.id  and refno=001 )  as balance 
from Ledger 
),
openingbalance(id,refno,transdate,cr,dr,balance)
As (
select top 1 '' id,'OPENING BAL','','','',balance
from summary
where transdate<@startdate
order by transdate desc
)


select id,refno,Cast(TransDate as varchar) as datetime,cr,dr,balance
from openingbalance
union

Select id,refno,Cast(TransDate as varchar)as datetime,cr,dr,balance
From summary

where transdate between @startdate and @enddate and refno=001 order by id
```